# Node.JS + Typescript - Valid to set database configuration with module.exports

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose in my node.js app (written in Typescript).

[Mongoose docs clearly show how to connect to their DB like this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html), however I want the config to be in a seperate file rather than my index.js.

Is it valid to do this i.e. this `module.exports` or is there another more recent approach I should be aware of:

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');

const server = '127.0.0.1:27017';
const database = 'test';

class Database {
  constructor() {
    this._connect()
  }

_connect(): void {
     mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${server}/${database}`)
       .then(() => {
         console.log('Database connection successful')
       })
       .catch(err => {
         console.error('Database connection error')
       })
  }
}

module.exports = new Database()
```

The other thing I was wondering about I guess that `_connect()` would only get called when I import it in some other file - or would that `module.exports = new Database()` automatically run that constructor?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create your configuration holder using a library like convict (https://www.npmjs.com/package/convict).
There you can specify all the configuration of your application.
Your `mongoFactory.ts` can simply contain a function that act as service factory for your Mongoose instance.

This is a js sample sample to avoid all the Ts entropy

```js
module.exports = config => {
 // create a new Mongoose instance
 // setup the mongoose instance based on the configuration
 // check for problems and in case let the caller know
 // return the mongoose instance
}
```